# Find the most used words in both text files

Tags: c++, arrays, string, file, fstream

I have two txt files both using the same words multiple times. I have managed to pull them both into arrays and formatted one of the non-formated txt files via a insertion sort.

Now I need to compare the two formatted arrays to find the most common words and also how many times they've been used.

I know I could use a for loop, going through each array, but I'm not sure how.
Any help?

edit:
Here is what I have so far.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

const int size = 100;
void checkIF(string x)
{
    fstream infile;
    cout << "Attempting to open ";
    cout << x;
    cout << "\n";
    infile.open(x);
    if( !infile )
    {
        cout << "Error: File couldn't be opened.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File opened succsesfully.\n";
    }
}
void checkFile()
{
    string f1 = "text1.txt", f2 = "abbreviations.txt";
    checkIF(f1);
    checkIF(f2);
}

string* readFiles(string txt1[],string abb[])
{
    fstream intxt1("text1.txt");
    fstream inabb("abbreviations.txt");
    int i = 0;
    while (!intxt1.eof())
    {   
        intxt1 >> txt1[i];
        //cout << txt1[i];
        i++;
    }
        while (!inabb.eof())
    {   
        inabb >> abb[i];
        //cout << abb[i];
        i++;
    }

    return txt1;
    return abb;
}

string* insertionSort(string txt1[], int arraySize)
{
    int i, j;
    string insert;

    for (i = 1; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        insert = txt1[i];
        j = i;
        while ((j > 0) && (txt1[j - 1] > insert))
        {
            txt1[j] = txt1[j - 1];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        txt1[j] = insert;
    }
    return txt1;
}


void compare(string txt1[],string abb[])
{

}

void main()
{
    string txt1Words[size];
    string abbWords[size];
    checkFile();
    readFiles(txt1Words,abbWords);
    insertionSort(txt1Words,100);
    compare(txt1Words,abbWords);
    system("Pause");
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried. You are much more likely to answers if you do this.

Comment: It would be very ineffective for any of us to begin modifying your code, based on what you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should start with a hashmap mapping each word to the amount of times it's used

Comment: How would I implement that? I'm unfamiliar with hashmap's

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map for each word you find.

```
std::map<std::string, int> wordmap;

for (int i = 0; i < arraylength; ++i)
{
   ++wordmap[array[i]];
}
```

I'm assuming that `array` is an array of `std::string`.
After that you can query the map with a specific word and get the count for that word.

```
wordmap[word] // returns count for word
```

Answer (score 0):

Insted of using arrays use vectors.

Not

```
string txt1Words[size];
```

But

```
vector<string> txt1Words;
```

The you can simply use

```
std::count(txt1Words.begin(), txt1Words.end(), word_to_search);
```

Comment: how can I make a loop to then find the amount of abbreviations are used in the txt1 File though? IF I implement a vector

Comment: amount of abbreviations? I didn't understand

Comment: How can I make a loop to find out how many letters from the abb array are inside the txt1 array?

Answer (score 0):

First off lets address the issue of "most used words in both text files". It really depends on how you define most used. You essentially have two sets of words with counts.

For example

File A: `"apple apple apple banana"`

File B: `"apple apple banana orange orange orange orange orange"`

which if you store it as a set of names and counts you get

File A: `{("apple",5), ("banana",1)}`

File B: `{("apple",2), ("banana",1), ("orange",5)}`

*Note: This isn't code its just a mockup notation.*

So in this small example what would be most used by **both** files?  But the question is should "apple" be the most used because it occurs in both files? Or should "orange" be the most used because it's used the most in one of the files?

I'm going to assume you want some sort of intersection of the two sets. So only words that appear in both files count. Additionally if I were you I would rank words by the minimum that they appeared, this way the 5 "apple"s in File A wouldn't weight "apple" too high because it only appears twice in File B.

So if we write that out in code you get something like this

```
class Word
{
public:
    std::string Token;
    int Count;

    Word (const std::string &token, int count)
        : Token(token), Count(count) {}
};
```

and

```
    std::map<std::string, int> FileA;
    std::map<std::string, int> FileB;

    std::vector<Word> intersection;

    for (auto i = FileA.begin(); i != FileA.end (); ++i)
    {
        auto bentry = FileB.find (i->first); //Look up the word from A in B
        if (bentry == FileB.end ())
        {
            continue; //The word from file A was not in file B, try the next word
        }

        //We found the word from A in B
        intersection.push_back(Word (i->first,std::min(i->second,bentry->second))); //You can replace the std::min call with whatever method you want to qualitate "most common"
    }

    //Now sort the intersection by Count
    std::sort (intersection.begin(),intersection.end(), [](const Word &a, const Word &b) { return a.Count > b.Count;});

    for (auto i = intersection.begin (); i != intersection.end (); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << (*i).Token << ": " << (*i).Count << std::endl;
    }
```

See it run:
http://ideone.com/jbPm1g

I hope that helps.